# Append duplicate rows as single record - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append the duplicated rows in one column. Duplication is based on some columns that need to be an exact match for a row to be declared as a match. the problem is we can't say how many repeated rows will be there so the solution needs to be generic.

I have tried some other solution but they are based on some user_id or key column. In my case, all columns except one have to be compared exactly. and appended columns should have the same column name.

Concat, merge, join tried everything nothing works.

I used the following code to find duplicated rows:

```
col = ['TITLE', 'ISSN', 'e-ISSN', 'ISBN', 'e-ISBN']
duplicated_data = data[data.duplicated(col, keep=False)]
```

here is Input :

```
------------------------------
DealName | Target | Category |
-----------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | A        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | B        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | None   | C        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | C        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | None   | D        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | Zab    | C        |
```

and want to convert it to something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DealName | Target | Category |DealName | Target | Category |DealName | Target | Category |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | A        |ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | B        |ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | C        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | None   | C        |ABC-XYZ  | None   | D        |
```

Suppose I have set the condition that the first two columns need to be matched in order to select the row, 
first, second and 4th row got appended as a single record
and third and fifth row got appended as another record

any idea how to do this?